# Infer Component Props within class accepting a component and props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to type a class, which takes in two parameters: a `Component` and `props` for that component.

```js
interface WrapperConfigArgs<Props = any> {
    Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
    props: Props
}

class WrapperConfig {
     constructor(args: WrapperConfigArgs) {
         Object.assign(this, args);
     }
}
```

Is there a way that I can infer the type of props, given a Component that is passed in here? For example, if I do:

```js
const HelloWorld = ({ name }: { name: string }) => <h1>Hello {name}</h1>

const wrapper = new WrapperConfig({
    component: HelloWorld, 
    props: // get type inference here for {name: string}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your class generic as well:

```
class WrapperConfig<P> {
    // now you can pass the type parameter to WrapperConfigArgs
    constructor(args: WrapperConfigArgs<P>) {
        Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2RRW)